# Can we always define a sesquilinear form on a vector space (without any additonal structure)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space with no additional structure. I want to endow this space with a sesquilinear form.

I don't know if $V$ should satisfy any condition to allow us defining sesquilinear form. 
So the question is that is there is any such condition?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying field of the vector space has to be $\mathbb C$, so that the complex conjugate is defined. (I suppose it could also be another field with a conjugation operation, like $\mathbb Q[i]$.)

Then every vector space has a sesquilinear form. For example you can always find a sesquilinear form by picking a basis and letting the form be the dot product in that basis.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the the underlying field is $C$. Thank you.